# Java GC output number format

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, jvm

In my gc logs, I have numbers formated as this:
`6,903: [GC [PSYoungGen: 218867K->23099K(229376K)] 218875K->23115K(753664K), 0,0243520 secs] [Times: user=0,08 sys=0,01, real=0,03 secs]`

So, HPJmeter is not able to load gc log file.

I want to change number format to this :
`8109.128: [GC [PSYoungGen: 109884K->14201K(139904K)] 691015K->595332K(1119040K), 0.0454530 secs]`

Any idea?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: try running with an en_US locale?

Comment: Thnx for your answer, I tried with -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US and nothing happened. Always a coma instead of a dot.

Comment: I mean your system locale. `LC_ALL` and friends if you're on unix.

Comment: Great! It works. Can you make an Answer with the command line as I can mark it as resolved and +1 ? Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since decimal marks are locale-specific you will have to set a system locale that uses points - java-internal locale doesn't seem to apply to JVM-internals.

On unix systems you can do that by setting an environment variable for the process:

`LC_ALL="en_US.utf8" java -jar ...`